# Sum of greatest integer functions question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that $[x+y] \leq [x] +[y]+1$

I started by supposing that $[x]=m$ and $[y]=n$, where $m,n \in \Bbb {Z}$.  So then that would mean that $m \leq x < m+1$ and $n \leq y < n+1$

But I don't know where to go from there.  I tried added the inequalities but that gave me $m+n \leq x+y < (m+1)+(n+1)$

How do I proceed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x\}=x-[x],\{y\}=y-[y]\iff x=[x]+\{x\},y=[y]+\{y\}$.

Noting that for $a\in\mathbb Z$
$$[a+b]=a+[b]$$
and that $0\le \{x\}\lt 1,0\le \{y\}\lt 1\Rightarrow 0\le \{x\}+\{y\}\lt 2\Rightarrow [\{x\}+\{y\}]\le 1$, we have
$$\begin{align}[x+y]&=[[x]+\{x\}+[y]+\{y\}]\\&=[x]+[y]+[\{x\}+\{y\}]\\&\le [x]+[y]+1.\end{align}$$

Comment: How would you know that $\{x\}+\{y\}=1$, since the definition only says that it's less than one? Also why did you have to let $x=[x]+\{x\}, y=[y]+\{y\}$?

Comment: I don't write $\{x\}+\{y\}=1$. What I wrote is $0\le \{x\}+\{y\}\le 1$. We have $0\le \{x\}\lt 1,\ 0\le \{y\}\lt 1$, right? So, we have $0\le \{x\}+\{y\}\lt 2\Rightarrow [\{x\}+\{y\}]=0\ \text{or}\ 1$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But where did $1,0$ come from?

Comment: I let $x=[x]+\{x\},y=[y]+\{y\}$ to separate the integer parts with the decimal parts. Then we can use $[a+b]=a+[b]$ when $a$ is an integer.

Comment: $0,1$ come from $0\le\{x\}+\{y\}\lt 2$. The integer part of $\{x\}+\{y\}$ is either $0$ or $1$, so we have $[\{x\}+\{y\}]=0\ \text{or}\ 1$. Hence, we have $[\{x\}+\{y\}]\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have one more question.  Why do we need to use $[a+b]=a+[b],a\in \Bbb {Z}$?  Why is it necessary to mention that in order to conclude that $[x+y] \geq [x]+[y]+1$?

Comment: Because I used the equality $[a+b]=a+[b]$ for $a\in\mathbb Z$ when I wrote $[[x]+[y]+\{x\}+\{y\}]=[x]+[y]+[\{x\}+\{y\}]$. Here, note that $[x]+[y]$ is an integer.

Comment: @user45417: Maybe I miss your point. If $[a+b]=a+[b]$ for $a\in\mathbb Z$ is obvious to you, you don't need to write it. Perhaps, you mean in the exam or something?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x = [x] + \epsilon_x$ and $y = [y] + \epsilon_y$, where $0\leq \epsilon_x <1$ and  $0\leq \epsilon_y <1$. Then $0\leq \epsilon_x + \epsilon_y<2$, so $[\epsilon_x + \epsilon_y] \leq 1$ and
$$[x+y] = [[x] + [y] + \epsilon_x + \epsilon_y]$$
$$=[x] + [y] + [\epsilon_x + \epsilon_y]$$
$$\leq [x] + [y] + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

From
$$x+y < (m+1) + (n+1) = [x]+[y]+2$$
you get
$$[x+y] \leq x+y < [x]+[y]+2$$
So, since they are integers and you have strict inequality, you can relax it to
$$[x+y] \leq [x]+[y]+2 - 1 = [x]+[y]+1$$